# Display null in the column where condition doesn't satisfy

Tags: sql

I have two tables

**TRAINING_EMPLOYEE**

[image]

**TRAINING_DEPARTMENT**

[image]

From both the tables, i want all the columns except DEPARTMENT_ID from the **TRAINING_EMPLOYEE** and column DEPARTMENT_NAME from the **TRAINING_DEPARTMENT**

I am doing this

```
SELECT TE.EMPLOYEE_ID,TE.FIRST_NAME,TE.LAST_NAME,TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE ,'DD-
MON-YYYY')HIRE_DATE,TD.DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM training_employee TE,
training_department TD  WHERE TE.DEPARTMENT_ID=TD.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

And i am getting this
 [image]

But i do want all the 4 rows of **TRAINING_EMPLOYEE** and null on  the Department_name if
**"TRAINING_EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT_ID<>TRAINING_DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_ID"**

Comment: You're using product specific SQL here (to_char). Please specify dbms!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `left join`.  And, it is hard because you are using archaic join syntax that doesn't really support it.  Here is a simple rule going forward:  never use a comma in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT TE.EMPLOYEE_ID, TE.FIRST_NAME, TE.LAST_NAME,
       TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') as HIRE_DATE, TD.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM training_employee TE LEFT JOIN
     training_department TD 
     ON TE.DEPARTMENT_ID = TD.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```